# How to Move the Marker in top of the Map Window in google map

Tags: google-maps-api-3, google-maps-markers, infobox

If i put `map.setCenter(marker.getPosition());` in OnClick Marker then the Marker Moves to Center Position of the Map Window.Which mean the Function get Marker Position and set it as center of the Map so the Marker Became Center Position of the Window.

Now i want this.
`map.SetCenter(top, center);` So that the marker will be in Top Center of the Map Window. Why i need this because When i click Marker the InfoBox opens downside of the maker and Half of the Info Box hide.

Please Give a Solution to solve this issue.

I am using this Info Box http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/examples.html

Comment: Set the zIndex of that marker to be a larger number than any of the others.

Comment: What? My problem is this... 1. In google map i am using InfoBox Plugin. So the Info Box opens below the Marker when i click a Marker.

The Map-canvas height is 400px(for example) So when i Click the Marker the Info window open bellow the Marker actually the Info Window having some more content and the height became 300px(for Example) so After Click the Marker the Info Window is Opens and the map set Center to the Clicked Marker And the Info Window's 50% in the Map and remaining is Hide, I have to move the Map to see the remaining Info Window. Is there any solution for this?

Comment: You should add all that to your question, preferably with an example so we can understand the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have disabled autopan for infobox..

remove **disableAutoPan : true** from your infobox properties...

```
infoBoxCluster = new InfoBox({
    content : yourContent,
    disableAutoPan : true,   // remove this line
    zIndex : 10000,
    closeBoxURL : '',
    pixelOffset : new google.maps.Size(42, -28)
});
```